# Up navigation with fragments and activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use the up navigation pattern and I'm having issues while using both fragments and activities. Let's say that I have activity A and that activity contains fragment a. Now I click something in fragment a and a fragmentTransaction happens with fragment b replacing a and a is put in the back stack. The "up" arrow now appears in my toolbar. This is all fine. Now I click something in fragment b and fire up activity B. A is B's parent. Now, B has an up arrow and I expect that when I touch it I would go to the top, i.e. finish activity B and the back stack of A would be popped so we end up with activity A containing fragment a and empty back stack.

My issue here is that when up is pressed in B, B is finished but A is still showing fragment b. Is there any way that I can make A not restore its' fragment back state onActivityResult or something like that so fragment b is never shown on up action from B?

What I have tried is using startActivityForResult when firing up B and popping A's fragment backstack onActivityResult but then b is briefly shown before the stack is popped. I just want A not to restore it's fragment state if up was pressed in B.

[image: Intended up behaviour]

Edit:
The pattern I'm using right now for the up navigation is that in my manifest I define A as B's parent and in activity B I have a toolbar which I set as a supportActionBar with setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled.

Comment: instead of doing it inside onActivityResult try doing it after calling startActivity(B).

Comment: Have you tried using [NavUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html) and declaring a parent activity in your manifest? I'd think you can use those functions to properly return to your parent activity, which should be reconstructed, once you push the up button in your options menu. You didn't really elaborate on the method you're using to perform the up navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. 
@GuilhE : the problem with this approach is that I want to make a difference between user pressing back or up in B.

Comment: @RyanJ : thanks for the suggestion! I'll try NavUtils tomorrow when I'll be back to work. I have a feeling that restarting the task might do it.

Comment: @RyanJ: your suggestion led my to the correct answer. I had my activity defined as "singleTop" in my manifest. Removing that made it work. Using NavUtils also works when you want this behaviour without clicking the back button.

Comment: @hordurh glad I helped point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my activity defined as "singleTop" in my manifest. If you remove that the up button causes the task to be recreated which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I have to wait a day before I can accept my own answer!

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: The pattern I'm using right now for the up navigation is that in
>   my manifest I define A as B's parent and in activity B I have a
>   toolbar which I set as a supportActionBar with
>   setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled.

said that my suggestion is popping A(b) when going to B.

When you call [navigateUpFromSameTask](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) it finishes the current activity and starts (or resumes) the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent activity is in the task's back stack, it is brought forward. That's why you are experiencing that behaviour.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are suggesting that when I'm calling startActivity(B) then I should pop the fragment backstack for A. In theory it makes sense since A would be clean on return but this has two issues.  First, I can't make fragmentTransaction after onSaveInstanceState and secondly, if the user presses the physical back button I want him to end up with A(b) on return to activity A. I thank you for the suggestion though, I didn't downvote you :)